# jquery - adding new content to page using onclick and .before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery, but am starting to get my head around it ( i think). I have a toggle ul (new restaurant) which works as a button, when i click on the ul button i want the button to create a new toggle above the pre-existing new restaurant button.

for example before

[image]

After

[image]

I am really trying to work this out on my own, but would just like a little guidance please.currently nothing is happening, just seen below:

[image]

script below:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $('li#order_open').click(function(){
              var $newRestaurant = $('<li id="order_open">New restaurant <a href="Menu.php";></a></li>');
              $('li').before($newRestaurant);
               });
```

```html
  <!--Restaurant toggle-->
            <a id="restt" class ="header"href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3 id="open">Your Restaurants</h3></a>
            <div id="Rest" style="display: none;"><div>

                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <!--                    <li id="order" class="rred"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">restaurant</a></li>-->
                        <li id="order_open" class="rgreen"><a href="javascript:void(0);">New restaurant</a></li>

                    </ul>
```

I have also tried:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
           $('li#order').click(function(){
               $('li#order').before('<li id="order">New restaurant <a href="Menu.php";></a></li>');
               });
```

```html
 <a id="restt" class ="header"href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3 id="open">Your Restaurants</h3></a>
            <div id="Rest" style="display: none;"><div>

                    <ul class="tabs">
                        <!--                    <li id="order" class="rred"><a href="Franchise-account-orders.php">restaurant</a></li>-->
                        <li id="order_open" class="rgreen"><a href="javascript:void(0);">New restaurant</a></li>

                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope, i understand your question right. You can add something before an element in this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#order_open').click(function(){
         //HTML you want to add
         var $newRestaurant = '<li id="order_open">New restaurant<a href="Menu.php";></a></li>';
         //insert before your clicked button
         $(this).before($newRestaurant);
     });
});
```

I've made a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6o593keg/

If you want an event handler on the inserted button you have to add a new event handler after you've inserted your new element:

```
$(this).click(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. i can how use this to guide me! it doesn't work but now i know the path i need to go down I'm sure it will be a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you create new jquery element in this row:

```
var $newRestaurant = $('<li id="order_open">New restaurant <a href="Menu.php";></a></li>');
```

so $newRestaurant points not into your clicked(selected) li but to the very new element that even doesn`t attached to the DOM.

You should use $( this ) to reference the attached element.

According to the documentation http://api.jquery.com/on/ :

> When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not
>   be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant
>   element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be
>   used with jQuery methods, use $( this )

Comment: @jerneva you should try something like his one:

$(document).ready(function(){
           $('li#order').click(function(){
               var $button = $(this);
               $(<li>New Restaurant</li>).before($button);
            });
})

Comment: Thank you, I've been trying different ways that logically make sense however don't work. i will try this and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple HTML element with same id, you should either increment the id or use class as selector

```
var $newRestaurant = $('<li class="order_open">New restaurant <a href="Menu.php";></a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use id's in dynamic content, use class instead.

If you just want to replicate a list item above it when it is clicked, you can use the `clone()`method as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').on('click','li.order_open', function() {
    $(this).before($(this).clone()); // or any custom content
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Restaurant toggle-->
<a id="restt" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3 id="open">Your Restaurants</h3></a>
<div id="Rest">
  <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="rgreen order_open"><a href="javascript:void(0);">New restaurant</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Note that you should use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so that the handler works for the injected elements as well.

Comment: Thank you. i can how use this to guide me! it doesn't work but now i know the path i need to go down I'm sure it will be a lot easier